# Change color of bars in barplot in relation to bar length

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

I have plotted a stacked barplot in base R:

```
set.seed(12)
dat <- matrix(sample(1:6, 6) , nrow = 3)
rownames(dat) <- c("A", "B", "C")
colnames(dat) <- c("blue", "green")
barplot(dat, beside = TRUE)
```

I'd like to

- assign one color to each group of bars and
- change the lightness (black to color) depending on bar length, so that a bar of length 6 has the full color.

like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

---

I have adapted @nya's answer in the following way:

```
set.seed(12)
dat <- matrix(sample(1:6, 6) , nrow = 3)
rownames(dat) <- c("A", "B", "C")
colnames(dat) <- c("blue", "green")

sequence <- seq(1, 6, 1)  # min = 1, max = 6, steps = 1
resolution <- length(sequence)
blues <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "blue"))(resolution)
greens <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "green"))(resolution)

cols <- c(blues[match(dat[, "blue"], sequence)],
          greens[match(dat[, "green"], sequence)])

mar.default <- c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1
par(mar = mar.default + c(2, 0, -2, 0))
barplot(dat, beside = TRUE, col = cols)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to create color gradients for plotting. Let's use a resolution of 10 colors from black to either blue or green.

```
res <- 10
blues <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "blue"))(res)
greens <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "green"))(res)
```

Second, we will use the function `cut` coerced to a factor to determine where in the gradient the values fit. We will use the factors (interpreted as numbers in `R` when subsetting rows) to select, which colors correspond to which values in data.

```
b.cut <- as.factor(cut(dat[, "blue"], breaks = res))
g.cut <- as.factor(cut(dat[, "green"], breaks = res))
cols <- c(blues[b.cut], greens[g.cut])
cols
```

These colors can be used for plotting. Note that I changed the name of your input data, because `data` is a function and a good programming practice is to avoid overwriting functions with variables.

```
barplot(dat, beside = TRUE, col = cols)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is a really nice solution. Alas, apparently I did not make my goal completely clear and have edited my question. What I want is that a bar of height 6 has the full color. Your solution assigns the full color to the highest bar of each group, even if it is shorter than 6.

Comment: I have adapted your solution to my needs. The code is in my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good. My solution will work as you request for `res = 6`.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify last line by adding a color argument `col` for including color options in the code. I modified the last line by adding appropriate hexagonal codes of the colors as given below:

```
barplot(data, beside = TRUE,col=c("#0000FF","#0066FF","#00FFFF","#ADFF2F","#008000","#006400"))
```

This is the plot I got.

[image]

The modified code is posted below. Change the hexagonal color code according to your wish. I referred `Color Cycling in R` section from [datamentor](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/color/) website.

```
set.seed(12)
data = matrix(sample(1:6, 6) , nrow = 3)
rownames(data) = c("A", "B", "C")
colnames(data) = c("blue", "green")
barplot(data, beside = TRUE,col=c("#0000FF","#0066FF","#00FFFF","#ADFF2F","#008000","#006400"))
```